# Can someone show me a picture of full grow Nepenthes Rafflesiana or Bicalcarata?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, tropical, nepenthes

Im trying to grow nepenthes **rafflesiana** and **bicalcarata** and im curious, i have seen many picture of this nepenthes species on google but the picture only show pitcher, stem, and leaf. Im also watch people on youtube who nursing this nepenthes species for 4, 5, and even 10 years more but only show small plant. Why i never saw full grow of this nepenthes species?

If you guys have full grow nepenthes **rafflesiana** or **bicalcarata**, could you guys show me the picture of this plant at full size? Sorry i just want to know what this plant looks like at full grow

Note: sorry for my bad english